# SQL Server Profiler trace different result on different system for same query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I run same JAVA application (spring/hibernate) on different system both use same SQL Server version.

I'm using SQL Server Profiler to trace a query which I run (exactly same) on both systems.

This is my SQL Server version on both system:
[image]

- Trace System 1 : [slow-system2.trc](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nOPUrmeopDQ2Sf-eZu7BoBrxLLINlxFw) query takes randomly between 100 - 300ms
- Trace System 2 : [fast.trc](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dxEqmPiHIMG0By6AAvqxcMh7bdFNYBNr) query takes randomly between 10-20ms

It seems here on slow-screenshot a query of "use database" takes "331ms" compared to fast.trc (0ms= : 
[image]

What can cause this difference just by running "use database" query ?

I tried on a 3th system running on sql express which is too slow [here is trace](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tLwgoMf_6i8z-jOnbgUvrGs_xrkduD2C)

It seems here on "sql express" it is due to the fact I have two additional **classEvent Audit Logout** that takes time :
[image]

Maybe I missed out some option on SQL Server?

Comment: First thing to do is compare query plans - looks like you captured it in your trace

Comment: as you said I capture them  and both are same as you can see (if you open *.trc) on both systems

Comment: a trace is not a query plan. Compare the query plans. It might be in that `showplan` line

Comment: Query plany is in the trace by clicking on it on bottom plans is displayed, it is same

Comment: Do your different systems run against the same SQL Server instance?

Comment: Add the EventSubClass column to the Audit Login/Audit Logout event. This will show whether the connection was pooled or not. A non-pooled connection must establish the network connection and authenticate, adding overhead. Perhaps there is a difference in the middleware polling config.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen It was not same but I updated my question to run on exactly same sql server instance, and here in trace we can see problem on "use database" I cant understand why

Comment: @DanGuzman I udpated my question to try on same sql server and here you can see problem is on "use database" please apolgise my first question version and get a look again thank you

Comment: @ebego, make sure the database is not set to auto close: `ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF;`

Comment: There's too many factors to be able to give a definitive sort of answer I suspect, so what you need to do is start removing possible factors to be able to create some sort of 'baseline' for when the issues starts. So what I recommend is going back to basic. Get the applications to run on one system, against one sql instance, exact same system, exact same database. If that cause problems, it's possible due to system spec (memory issues etc) and/or database config (closing, pooling).

Comment: @DanGuzman you make my day!!!! never thought this is set to true! thank you! can you make an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long duration of the `USE` statement indicates the database may be set to `AUTO_CLOSE ON`. Overhead is incurred during database startup when it must be opened.

The setting can be changed with:

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF;
```